# How to get the current working directory in Kotlin?

Tags: java, file, kotlin, directory, path

I need to know the full path of my current working directory of my simple application using Kotlin.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will provide the full absolute path from where application will run.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

val path = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
```

Comment: What library is Path a part of?  How do I import that?

Comment: import java.nio.file.Paths

Comment: That returns me slash but not path per se... "/"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

Answer (score 8):

You can also get it from System.

```
val path = System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with kotlin on android try with:

**Kotlin**

```
applicationInfo.dataDir
```

if you are working on android using **Java.**

```
getApplicationInfo().dataDir
```

it returns a String.

Comment: In Kotlin, I am doing getApplicationContext().dataDir however it returns something like /data/user/0/com.exa.mypackage/ not the actual path....

Comment: The question does not explicitly mention that the application is Android-specific, so how does this answer help answer the question?

Comment: @Edric you are right, Now I just changed my answer adding that if they are using kotlin for  android they may check the line of code I wrote